Ubuntu 24.04 does not read a USB stick, my phone and windows and ubuntu 22.04 do
I have a USB stick that can also be used by my cell phone.
If I try to read the stick, Ubuntu 24.04 gives me this error message:
"Error mounting /dev/sdb ....: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

However, the stick is read normally by Windows and my cell phone, as well as by Ubuntu 22.04 installed in another partition of the same PC.
Any ideas?
Thanks to all who responded and especially codlord.
syslog suggested using ntfsfix, which solved the problem.

Maybe it's a stick without a partition table, so you'd need the mount option "loop" (see the "man mount" documentation).

edit the mount option or repair the fs by the disk utility

I think that error message is fairly generic and not always useful. Have a look in your /var/log/syslog and/or do sudo dmesg -w then connect the device to see if it says what the actual error is. I had this recently on 24.04 with a USB connected HDD. Syslog said something about a dirty flag and in my case I just cleared the flag with sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1 but without knowing your underlying error it's impossible to say what you need to do to fix it.

Glad you have solved it, but I cant see HOW you solved it (or point me to an appropriate previous answer)
I am having what looks like a similar problem.

In my case it is an NTFS format flash drive (that I am happy to reformat to work on both Ubuntu 24.04 and older versions.

When I posted my question I was convinced that the problem was with the Ubuntu 24.04 operating system. I tried using ntfsfix, but I got nothing, probably because of my ignorance. I remembered that on another occasion Gparted had suggested me to use chkdsk /f under Windows, so I tried that solution, which worked. Sorry if I was a bit hasty and imprecise in communicating the cessation of my problem, but it seemed to me that it was only the result of my great inexperience and that it did not interest others. Now I read that someone could have a similar problem ...

chkdsk is a bit misleading. What @codlord said in a comment is correct:

sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1 but without knowing your underlying error
it's impossible to say what you need to do to fix it

I did the same, and it works.

That error message is fairly generic and not always useful.
Have a look in your /var/log/syslog (system log messages) and/or do sudo dmesg -w (kernel messages) then connect the device to see if it says what the actual error is.
I had this recently on 24.04 with a USB connected HDD. Syslog said something about a dirty flag and in my case I just cleared the flag with sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1.
You need to know the underlying error before determining the fix.
